# Magneto 2 : how to call code in require js

Tags: magento2, jquery, requirejs

How to write code in require js, I created layout default.xml file and added code like this

```
       <link src="Test::js/custom.js"/>
```

And I created web/js/custom.js and wrote like this

```
 jQuery(document).ready( function() {
 alert("Hai Hello");
 jQuery('#text').css('display', 'none');
 jQuery("#btn").click(function(){
 jQuery('#text').css('display', 'block');
    if ((jQuery('#text-data').val()) === '') {
        jQuery('#error-msg').css('display', 'block');
       
        return false;
    }
    else {
        jQuery('#error-msg').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
});
```

But it is not working. How to convert this code to require js. Plz help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code which will work your custom JS as expected.

web/js/custom.js

```
 define([
        'jquery'
    ], function($) {
        "use strict";
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
 alert("Hai Hello");
 jQuery('#text').css('display', 'none');
 jQuery("#btn").click(function(){
 jQuery('#text').css('display', 'block');
    if ((jQuery('#text-data').val()) === '') {
        jQuery('#error-msg').css('display', 'block');
       
        return false;
    }
    else {
        jQuery('#error-msg').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
});
    }
    });
```

Please note JS path should be correct and run the Magento cache:flush and static content command to see the changes in the frontend.
Please let me know if you are facing any issue.

Or you can add js in phtml file as well. Please review the below example

```
 require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
     //your js code here  
 });
```

### Examples:

Inside the require function, you can directly access jQuery functionality in place by using either `jQuery` or its short form alias, the dollar `$` sign. For example:

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
  jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    alert("Page loaded.");
  });
});
```

Or

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
  $(document).ready( function() {
    alert("Page loaded.");
  });
});
```

Please let me know if you need any other help

Comment: what is "use strict" here

Comment: Strict mode removes certain language constructs and behaviors that make optimizing javascript difficult, or that have bene proven to lead to bugs. It's a way for programmers to opt-in to “better” javascript, but leaves old code to run as is.

Comment: so can i add "use strict" also in my code

Comment: I think yes....

Comment: instead of define we can use require? and <link src> or <script src>?

Comment: No, whenever you create custom JS, then we have to use define otherwise it may not work. Or if you want to add JS in phtml file then you can require.

Comment: Thanks ur code is working, am accepting ur answer. But they asks like you are adding custom.js file always, even if functionality is disable.

Please, just use require in PHTML file only if functionality is enabled. How to do this? Plz let me know

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check and accept my answer if helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131556/discussion-between-user0434-and-nits).

Answer (score 1):

your code is correct!
just you have missed  name in link tag.
change code inside link tag in this form.(given below).

1. `<link src="<vendor>_<module>::js/custom.js"/>`

for more information to link the click devdocs documentation.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html

I hope its work perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your layout file is in correct place and has a correct structure:
   **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>

   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <head>
           <link src="Vendor_Module::js/custom.js"/>
       </head>
   </page>
   ```
2. And here is how your custom.js file should look like:
   **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/custom.js**

   ```
   require([
       'jquery',
       'domReady!'
   ], function ($) {

       alert("Hai Hello");

       var textEl = $('#text'),
           btnEl = $("#btn");

       textEl.css('display', 'none');
       btnEl.bind('click', function(){
           textEl.css('display', 'block');
           if ($('#text-data').val() === '') {
               $('#error-msg').css('display', 'block');
               return false;
           } else {
               $('#error-msg').css('display', 'none');
           }
       });
   });
   ```